# Symfony2 - Autowiring Services with the Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am able to use the new autowire feature of Symfony2 to inject a service into a service. However, I cannot inject a service into a controller. What am I not doing/doing wrong?

This is my services.yml file:

```
services:
    home_controller:
        class:  AppBundle\Controller\HomeController
        autowire:  true
```

This is my ServiceConsumerDemo:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class ServiceConsumerDemo {

    private $serviceDemo;

    public function __construct(ServiceDemo $serviceDemo) {
        $this->serviceDemo = $serviceDemo;
    }

    public function getMessage(){
        return $this->serviceDemo->helloWorld();
    }
}
```

This is ServiceDemo:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class ServiceDemo 
{    
    public function helloWorld(){
        return "hello, world!";
    }
}
```

This is HomeController (which works):

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     *
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $message[0] = $this->get('service_consumer_demo')->getMessage();
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($message);
    }
}
```

This is HomeController which **does not work**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Services\ServiceConsumerDemo;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    private $serviceConsumerDemo;

    public function __construct(ServiceConsumerDemo $serviceConsumerDemo) {

        $this->serviceConsumerDemo = $serviceConsumerDemo;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     *
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $message[0] =  $this->serviceConsumerDemo->getMessage();
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($message);
    }
}
```

This is the error thrown:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Controller\HomeController::__construct() must be an instance
>   of AppBundle\Services\ServiceConsumerDemo, none given,

How do I access the Services in the Controller? I understand I need to declare the controller as a service. So I'm mentioning the controller in the services.yml file. Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: Your route annotation is not defining the controller as a service so regular new is being used: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#controller-as-service

Comment: Perfect! Can you write the answer below so i can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @Cerad has the correct answer!

Comment: why would you want to inject into the controller? It has access to the container anyway

Answer (score 1):

#### Symfony 3.3+ May 2017 UPDATE!

Symfony 3.3 allows native way to approach this.

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true # all services in this config are now autowired

    App\: # no more manual registration of similar groups of services 
        resource: ../{Controller}
```

**This means `App\Controller\SomeController` is autowired by default and to be found in `app/Controller/SomeController.php` file.**

You can read:

- [more about `_defaults` here](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#1-let-s-add-code-defaults-code)
- and [more about PSR-4 service registration](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration)

---

Thanks to autowiring in Symfony 2.8+ I could create bundle, that adds autowiring even for controllers: [Symplify/ControllerAutowire](https://github.com/Symplify/ControllerAutowire)

You can read more about this in [the article](http://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2016/03/10/autowired-controllers-as-services-for-lazy-people).

Usage is as simple as:

```
class YourController
{
    public function __construct(SomeDependency $someDependency)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Nothing more is required.

Answer (score 1):

By default, controllers are not considered as services, so you can't use autowiring with them.

However, it's a simple enough fix - add a `@Route` annotation on the **class** (i.e. not on an action method in the class) with a service definition.

From the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#controller-as-service):

> The @Route annotation on a controller class can also be used to assign
>   the controller class to a service so that the controller resolver will
>   instantiate the controller by fetching it from the DI container
>   instead of calling new PostController() itself.

For example:

```
/** 
 * @Route(service="app_controller") 
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{

    private $service;

    public function __construct(SomeService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    /** @Route("/") */
    public function someAction()
    {
        $this->service->doSomething();
    }

}
```

and in your config:

```
app_controller:
    class:  AppBundle\Controller\AppController
    autowire: true
```

Comment: FWIW - I stole this answer from @Cerad's comment.

Answer (score -1):

You do not pass service to your controller in services.yml. Change it to:

```
services:
    service_demo:
        class:  AppBundle\Services\ServiceDemo
    service_consumer_demo:
        class:  AppBundle\Services\ServiceConsumerDemo
        autowire:   true
    home_controller:
        class:  AppBundle\Controller\HomeController
        autowire:  true
        arguments:
            service: "@service_consumer_demo"
```

Comment: Um that didn't work. Btw, since i'm using the autowire feature, shouldn't i ***not*** require explicitly mentioning the service?

Comment: Describe the error, which trows after you have changed services.yml from my answer

Comment: and what if you remove autowire from config?